# Is there a node.js implementation of an OpenID consumer?

Tags: openid, node.js

Looking for an OpenID consumer in node.js

It is not on this list http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Is there one?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've written OpenID for node.js and shared the code at https://github.com/havard/node-openid. It is a fully OpenID 2.0 (and partially OpenID 1.1) compliant Relying Party.

For more information on the library, you can also read the [announcement blog post](http://ox.no/posts/openid-for-node-js).

**UPDATE:** As of 2011-09-04, the library is a fully OpenID 1.0/1.1 compliant Relying Party as well.

Comment: And i just added a sample in the code for those using expressjs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ***Passport*** will be good for your needs:

[**passport**](http://passportjs.org/) *(copied from their website)*

> Passport is authentication middleware for Node.js. Extremely flexible
>   and modular, Passport can be unobtrusively dropped in to any
>   Express-based web application. A comprehensive set of strategies
>   support authentication using a username and password, Facebook,
>   Twitter, and more.

**Features:**

- 140+ authentication strategies
- Single sign-on with OpenID and OAuth
- Easily handle success and failure
- Supports persistent sessions
- Dynamic scope and permissions
- Pick and choose required strategies
- Implement custom strategies
- Does not mount routes in application
- Lightweight code base

Comment: Note that if you're looking to support OpenID only, there's no reason to use Passport, as its OpenID module is just a wrapper around OpenID for Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

[Everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) is on the list at http://openid.net/developers/libraries/ but it is listed under "everyauth" instead of "Javascript" or "node.js".

It claims to be a "node.js auth package (password, facebook, & more) for Connect and Express apps" and claims to work with ~30+ services, including OpenID. Facebook, Twitter, Google, LinkedIn, DropBox, Tumblr, GitHub, and a bunch of others.

It is being actively developed, judging from the recent github commits for June 2013.

Comment: Note that if you're looking to support OpenID only, there's no reason to use Everyauth, as its OpenID module is just a wrapper around OpenID for Node.js.